# Таблица очищается после рестарта MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

После рестарта MySQL все данные в таблице пропадают и таблица становиться чиста, как будто они хранятся в кеше.

Как сделать, чтобы они не пропадали?

Дистрибутив: ubuntu 14

Comment: Как таблицу создавали?

Comment: Какой  движок у таблицы? MEMORY?

Answer (score 2):

похоже, что для данной таблицы выбран «движок» («*engine*») под названием `memory` (т.е., таблица хранится в памяти).

уточнить можно, например, командой:

```
> show create table имя_таблицы;
```

будет показано, какая именно sql-команда «создаёт» данную таблицу. пример вывода:

```
...
... create table `имя_таблицы` (...) engine=название_движка ...
```

---

посмотреть список всех поддерживаемых вашим экземляром *mysqld* движков можно, например, так:

```
> show engines;
```

пример вывода:

```
+--------------------+---------+-
| Engine             | Support | 
+--------------------+---------+-
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | 
| CSV                | YES     | 
| MyISAM             | YES     | 
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | 
| MEMORY             | YES     | 
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | 
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | 
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | 
| FEDERATED          | NO      | 
+--------------------+---------+-
```

тот движок, про который написано `default` в столбце `support` — будет использоваться по умолчанию, если в команде `create table ...` движок не указан явно.

сменить движок (теоретически, доступно не для любых пар движков) уже существующей таблицы можно командой:

```
> alter table имя_таблицы engine = название_движка;
```